# How to programmatically install packages from init.el (using emacs27)?

Tags: package

I have this in my init.el file

```
(when (not (package-installed-p 'geiser))
  (package-install 'geiser))
```

But when I start emacs, I get the error

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading '/home/ykp/.emacs.d/init.el':

error: Package 'geiser-' is unavailable.
```

How do I fix this? I just want to avoid manually installing my package and do it through my initialization script.

Comment: The error message refers to package `geiser-`, with a hyphen, not to package `geiser`. Does your code perhaps use `geiser-` where it should use `geiser`?

Comment: nope -- not using geiser anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `package-refresh-contents` before trying to install a package. From <kbd>C-h f package-refresh-contents</kbd>:

> Download descriptions of all configured ELPA packages. For each
> archive configured in the variable `package-archives', inform Emacs
> about the latest versions of all packages it offers, and make them
> available for download.

So you could try something like this somewhere near the beginning of your `init.el`, at least before you try to install the packages you want:

```
(require 'package)
(package-refresh-contents)
```

Comment: you might also want to look at [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) and the `:ensure t` option in particular